# Is penetration of a fast particle deep into a medium a quantum mechanical effect?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, kinetic-theory, gas, mean-free-path

Consider the cosmic rays. The muons can travel 15000 meters through the atmosphere and get down to sea level. If this is not a quantum mechanical effect, its penetration depth is determined by the **mean free path**.

The mean free path is about 68 nm on the sea level.

Actually, by classical mechanics, the penetration depth is purely determined by the mean free path and independent of the initial velocity of the injecting particle. Only by quantum mechanics, the scattering rate depends on the velocity of the injecting particle and generally is the smaller the larger the velocity.

Is this argument reasonable?

Answer (score 2):

Where did you get the number

> The mean free path is about 68 nm on the sea level.

Muon is very penetrating, the  LHC detectors have a lot of mass around to be able to measure the muons leaving the interaction after traversing a lot of mass.

In general it certainly is quantum mechanical interactions that degrade the energy of the muon.

[image: muon penetration]

This [article:](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2011/reviews/rpp2011-rev-cosmic-rays.pdf) has a figure:
Figure 24.6:Vertical muon intensity vs depth (1 km.w.e. = 10^5g cm^−2of standard
rock).

> muons lose energy by ionization and by radiative processes: bremsstrahlung, direct production ofe+e−pairs,and photonuclear interactions.

Comment: I got the number from wiki. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_free_path

Comment: I see, it is  not a useful number for penetration of cosmic rays, because the succesive interactions , which give the mean free path, do not deter the particle except by loosing a small part of its energy. Most interactions of charged elementary particles are electromagnetic, so there are many of them, but it is the energy loss  that will characterize how deeply they penetrate, and the coupling of the interaction. The scattering is a quantum mechanical effect.

Answer (score 0):

One important factor here is relativistic length contraction: in the frame of the muon, the distance travelled is much less.  See for example [this page](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/muon.html) for a very relevant example discussing your question.

Comment: I do not think it is primarily a relativistic effect. Let us take another example. See the first figure in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode_ray. Although I do not know the density of gas in the chamber, I would presume that the mean free path is much smaller than the diameter of the glowing circle.

Comment: @Jiang-minZhang  Cathode rays are not relativistic, travel in vacuum rather than air, and not over 1000s of meters.  I'm not sure the comparison is relevant.